# Symfony search functionality

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to implement a search feature to allow users to search for items within a specific entity, however im not sure how i should approach this, basically i current have in my twig file:

```
 <form id="form_search" action="{{ path('search') }}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name ="find">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"></button>
</form>
```

And then within my controller i have:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('GET'))
    {
        echo 'get';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'post';
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:Search:index.html.twig', array(

    ));
}
```

I was thinking to get the input from the search input field from the parameter. However, theirs no way of seperating whether the user has just loaded the page or has actually submitted the form.. as you can see, ive tried to gain an idea on how to do this by seperating stuff:

So if the user has loaded the page it won't do a search.. however if the user submits the form then it'll perform a search but for some reason even when i submit the form it prints 'get' rather than 'post'

Why is this?

Comment: Try to echo this in your controller `$request->getMethod()` and also add `method="post"` to your form tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a new  function in your controller, that you will use for making your search, this is:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{  
   /**
    * @Route("/", name="index")
    */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    { 

   return $this->render('Bundle:Search:index.html.twig', array());
   }
   /**
    * @Route("/", name="search")
    */
    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
         $your_value =  $request->get("find"); 
         //implement your search here, 
         $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:YourEntity');
         $result = $repository->findBy(array("field_name"=>$your_value));
         //Here you can return your data in JSON format or in a twig template 
    }
}
```

Do not forget to Define your Entity class, I recommend you to take a look at this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Comment: well, you said "You need to define" :)